# Unable to calculate pseudo-inverse $A^TA$

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

I'm trying to calculate the pseudo-inverse of $A^TA$ as described in [this](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~jwarren/papers/techreport02408.pdf) paper:

> The SVD is particularly simple to calculate when
>   the matrix is of the form $A^TA$ because $U=V$ and the rows of $U$
>   are the eigenvectors of $A^TA$ and the singular values in $D$ are the
>   eigenvalues of $A^TA$.
>   Since $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices, the inverse of $M$ is then
>   $M^{-1}=V^TD^{-1}U$

Since the pseudo-inverse of a non-singular matrix is it's inverse I tried to do this with a non-singular matrix and see if I get the inverse. I tried it with the following:

$A^TA = \begin{pmatrix}
90 & 51 \\
51 & 29
\end{pmatrix}$ where $A = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
9 & 5
\end{pmatrix}$

Eigenvalues and eigenvectors:

$\lambda_1 = 118.9243;$  $\lambda_2=0.0757;$ $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0.5671
\end{pmatrix};$ $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1.7632
\end{pmatrix}$

$U = V=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0.5671 \\
1 & -1.7632
\end{pmatrix}$
$D = \begin{pmatrix}
118.9243 & 0\\
0 & 0.0757
\end{pmatrix}$

And my result is:

$V^TD^{-1}U= \begin{pmatrix}
13.22 & -23.29 \\
-23.29 & 41.07
\end{pmatrix} \neq (A^TA)^{-1}$

Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V$ should be an **orthogonal** matrix and its two rows should be a set of two orthonormal eigenvectors of $A^TA$. Therefore the correct $V$ should be $\pmatrix{\frac{v_1^T}{\|v_1\|}\\ \frac{v_2^T}{\|v_2\|}}$, but you wrongly took $V$ as $\pmatrix{v_1^T\\ v_2^T}$ without normalising the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm revising my previous post due to further research and my misconception on the pseudoinverse.

The pseudoinverse for a square matrix can exist even if the matrix is singular. If a square matrix is not singular the pseudoinverse is unique and should equal the inverse. I tested your example in Matlab and indeed the pseudoinverse and inverse are equal but not equal to your result.

The reason being is it appears your U and V matrices in the SVD are not correct. It should be

$U=V=\begin{bmatrix}-0.8698 & -0.4933\\-0.4933 & 0.8698\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Pick up the thread at the eigenvectors or the product matrix. The ordering was mixed. It should be:
$$
  v_{1} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 1.76322 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right], 
\qquad
  v_{2} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 -0.567144 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right].
$$
Normalized, these are the column vectors of the domain matrix:
$$
\mathbf{V} =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.869844 & -0.493327 \\
 0.493327 & 0.869844 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Next, $\mathbf{U} \ne \mathbf{V}!$:
$$
\mathbf{A} =   \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{T} 
\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{A} \, \mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{-1}.
$$
Now perform your cross check:
$$
\begin{align}
%
\mathbf{A} &= \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{T} \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 9 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
&=
% U
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 0.329767 & 0.944062 \\
 0.944062 & -0.329767 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% Sigma
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 10.9052 & 0. \\
 0. & 0.275097 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% V^T
\left[
\begin{array}{rc}
 0.869844 & 0.493327 \\
 -0.493327 & 0.869844 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$
All null spaces are trivial and the classic inverse is the pseudoinverse:
$$
  \mathbf{A}^{-1} = \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = \mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{-1} \, \mathbf{U}^{T} =
\frac{1}{3}
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
 -5 & 2 \\
 9 & -3 \\
\end{array}
\right].
$$